# Marshal a list with Generic wrapper object

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, marshalling, moxy

I'm attempting to follow the tutorial [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/creating-generic-list-wrapper-in-jaxb.html) and seem to be struggling with serialization.  When I marshal an object, I get the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<WrapBean>com.lists.beans.ChildBean@2df36f51com.lists.beans.ChildBean@49114668</WrapBean>
```

I'm expecting something more like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<WrapBean>
  <ChildBean>
    <first_name>[name]</first_name>
    <last_name>[name[</last_name>
    <age>[age]</age>
  </ChildBean>
  <ChildBean>
    ...
  </ChildBean>
</WrapBean>
```

This is my main method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext context = (JAXBContext) JAXBContext.newInstance(WrapBean.class);

        ArrayList<ChildBean> children = new ArrayList<ChildBean>();
        ChildBean c1 = new ChildBean();
        c1.setFname("larry");
        c1.setLname("sanderson");
        c1.setAge("13");
        children.add(c1);

        ChildBean c2 = new ChildBean();
        c2.setFname("amber");
        c2.setLname("smith");
        c2.setAge("11");
        children.add(c2);     

        QName qName = new QName("WrapBean");
        WrapBean wrapper = new WrapBean(children);
        JAXBElement<WrapBean> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement<WrapBean>(qName, WrapBean.class, wrapper);
        marshaller.setProperty(JAXBMarshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, System.out);
    }
```

I can post the bean classes, if needed, but there's only the setters and getters and the annotations necessary to get the element names right.  Can anyone help me with what I'm missing?

**EDIT**:  I also wanted to mention, the wrapper object is the exact same as the tutorial:

```
public class Wrapper<T> {

    private List<T> items;

    public Wrapper() {
        items = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public Wrapper(List<T> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
    public List<T> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the `JAXBContext` aware of the items that will be in the collection.

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(WrapperBean.class, ChildBean.class);
```

Comment: Thank you Blaise, that is exactly what I was missing.  Should have looked closer given it was the only thing I was doing differently.  Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Blaise, I am wondering if you know of a way to create a wrapper for individual items inside the list? I posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28946378/jaxb-wrapper-class-for-external-rest-api

Basically, I am using JAXB with a REST api. The contents of the items are the same, but based on if it is a request or response, it will have a root element of <request> or <response> but then for each item in that list, it will have a element of <result> or <entry> based on response or request. 

Thanks